# Connecting to Odata 4 returns 406 Not Acceptable

Tags: java, web-services, rest, odata

I am trying to connect to Odata 4 and I got a 406 error.

```
The content-type range '[application/json;odata.metadata=full]' is not supported. [HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable]
```

Full stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.olingo.client.api.communication.ODataClientErrorException: The content-type range '[application/json;odata.metadata=full]' is not supported. [HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable]
    at org.apache.olingo.client.core.communication.header.ODataErrorResponseChecker.checkResponse(ODataErrorResponseChecker.java:73)
    at org.apache.olingo.client.core.communication.request.AbstractRequest.checkResponse(AbstractRequest.java:53)
    at org.apache.olingo.client.core.communication.request.AbstractODataRequest.doExecute(AbstractODataRequest.java:324)
    at org.apache.olingo.client.core.communication.request.retrieve.ODataServiceDocumentRequestImpl.execute(ODataServiceDocumentRequestImpl.java:57)
    at org.apache.olingo.client.core.communication.request.retrieve.ODataServiceDocumentRequestImpl.execute(ODataServiceDocumentRequestImpl.java:37)
    at com.acc.odata.OlingoConnect.main(OlingoConnect.java:23)
```

Below is the code i am trying to get the connection to odata using olingo jars

```
String serviceRoot = "http://localhost:8080/odata-server-sample/cars.svc";
ODataClient client = ODataClientFactory.getV4();
ODataServiceDocumentRequest req = client.getRetrieveRequestFactory()
    .getServiceDocumentRequest(serviceRoot);
ODataRetrieveResponse<ODataServiceDocument> res = req.execute();
ODataServiceDocument serviceDocument = res.getBody();
Collection<String> entitySetNames = serviceDocument.getEntitySetNames();
Map<String, URI> entitySets = serviceDocument.getEntitySets();
Map<String, URI> singletons = serviceDocument.getSingletons();
Map<String, URI> functionImports = serviceDocument.getFunctionImports();
URI productsUri = serviceDocument.getEntitySetURI("Cars");
```

What is wrong with my implementation?

Answer (score 0):

That's because the service document's Content-Type is application/xml, not the "application/json;odata.metadata=full". maybe you should add the header "Accept"